Lichtenberg figures
I am writing a story in which a character is wearing an insulated suit (rubber) to protect himself from being severely injured or killed by electrocution, but it will not fully protect him from a very powerful strike. In this hypothetical situation, if he were struck, would Lichtenberg figures form on his skin? From what I can tell Lichtenberg figures are not actually burns, but damaged blood vessels. So perhaps the suit would protect him from surface burns, but could still cause damage to blood vessels/nerves/etc? Just looking for someone more knowledgeable than I am about what happens to the body when electrocuted, and about how electricity works in general. :) Thank you!

Where is the electricity flowing, i.e. the entry and exit points?

Greetings! You do ask an interesting question, but it doesn't seem to be a good fit for our particular forum. Since you're asking for basics of electricity, lightning, lichtenberg figures, I'd suggest you delete this question here and ask it on one of the science focused forums. Maybe physics or biology or medicine. Here, we really deal with how real world things like electricity interplay within the fictional context. So if you were to get a better understanding of your question in one of the other forums, we'd be happy to help you apply that knowledge to your worldbuilding!

(cont) As such, since this isn't a worldbuilding question, I'm going to vote to close it. Not because it's bad, but simply to protect your question from overly eager answerers!

Probably Not
Lichtenberg figures are a sign of very severe electrocution.  Very few man-made sources of electricity are even powerful enough to cause them; so, most often they are caused by particularly bad lightning strikes.  If you've been struck by lightning badly enough to cause lichtenberg figures, your odds of survival are only about 50% which is much worse than the typical lightning strike which is about 90%.
So, if you are in a high voltage situation where you are wearing a suit that is theoretically designed to dampen expected voltages enough to safe your life, then it stands to reason that it will dampen the shock enough to prevent the formation of Lichtenberg figures.
Survivors of with Lichtenberg figures seems to all have in common very brief but powerful exposures to electricity so a suit that dampens the flow over time is more likely to prevent Lichtenberg figures than it is to prevent death.
I only found vague references to 2 cases of people getting Lichtenberg figures from man-made power sources which involved 20,000+ volt power lines.  The source did not say if both were fatal, but the likelihood of surviving such a shock is slim to none.  Even with safety cutoffs, the time in which such a system could detect a problem and cut the power, is much longer than the duration of a lightning strike increasing your odds of death to more or less 100%.  So it is plausible to get zapped hard enough to get the lines, but I would not count on surviving it.
... unless he is working with short pulsed, high energy device
The only case I can think of where you might survive it from a man-made source would be involving a high energy pulsed device like certain laboratory lasers.  For example, the petawatt lasers used in high end research laboratories can discharge incredible amounts of power in pulses so short that they are measured in femtoseconds.  If you were to accidentally have your hand in the wrong place, I could foresee such a system recreating the conditions of a survivable lightning strike resulting in Lichtenberg figures, but such devices are very rare and specialized pieces of equipment.

Public service announcement: the safety cutoffs of medium voltage power lines, such as the 20 kV line mentioned in the answer, typically react in about one alternating current cycle at best. That's on the order of 20 milliseconds, three orders of magnitude longer than a lightning strike. Do not even think to touch a live conductor of a medium or high voltage power line. Even if the cutoff devices work perfectly, your chances of surviving the experience are very very slim.

@AlexP Good point.  I've updated my answer to reflect this issue while giving a more reasonable example of a possibly survivable man-made power source.
